# How do I increase the clock update (sync) frequency?

Tags: windows-8, time

I use Windows 8.1

I would like to sync my time at a greater frequency then what is permitted by the GUI choices.  How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient

modify the value for: SpecialPollInterval

If you select decimal instead of hex - it will reveal a number.  That is how long (in seconds) windows leaves between sync attempts.

NIST for example, [warns here](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) to send update requests no more often than every four seconds.